# If/then statement for Powershell to check Azure Automation Runbook Schedule

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, scripting, azure-automation

I am stumped on what exactly I am missing here. I am trying to author a script to check if a schedule is enabled or not enabled in an Azure Automation Account, and then take an action with an if/then statement.

I have tried a couple different iterations but essentially I am not able to pull the results of my "Get" cmdlet and pipe them into my Set cmdlet. If the "IsEnabled" = True I want to enable the schedule, if = false I want to write output that it is already enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationschedule?view=azps-9.1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/set-azautomationschedule?view=azps-9.1.0

```
#Check and Enable Start Jobs
Get-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "XXXXXX" -Name "XXXXX" -ResourceGroupName "XXXXX"

Write-Output "IsEnabled" | Set-AzAutomationSchedule

if ($IsEnabled -eq "False") {

Set-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "XXXXX" -Name "XXXX" -IsEnabled "True" -ResourceGroupName "XXXX"
}
elseif ($IsEnabled -eq "True") {
    Write-Host "Scheduled jobs are already enabled" -ForegroundColor Green
}
#Check and Enable Stop Jobs
Get-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "XXXXX" -Name "Scheduled-StopVM" -ResourceGroupName "XXXXXX"

if ($IsEnabled -eq "False") {

Write-Output "IsEnabled" | Set-AzAutomationSchedule 

Set-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "XXXX" -Name "XXXXX" -IsEnabled "True" -ResourceGroupName "XXXXX"
}
elseif ($IsEnabled -eq "True") {
    Write-Host "Scheduled jobs are already enabled" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to check if a schedule is enabled or not by connecting to `Azureautomationaccount` from PowerShell and it worked for me as shown below:

***Script:***

```
$infoo = Get-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "<AutomationAccountName>" -Name "new" -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>"
if ($infoo.IsEnabled -eq $true){
Write-Host "Scheduled jobs are already enabled" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
if ($infoo.IsEnabled -eq $False) {
Set-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "<AutomationAccountName>" -Name "new" -IsEnabled $True -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>"
}
```

***If the schedule is enabled, I got the following output:***

[image]

***If it is not enabled, then use*** `set-azautomationschedule -IsEnabled $true` ***enables the schedule***.

[image]

***Previously, a schedule's status in the portal was disabled***:

[image]

***Status is set to*** ***"On"*** ****Azure Automation Account* in portal after enabling it***.

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! looks like we got pretty much the same of doing it: I was able to figure it out as well. I had to put the cmdlets in a variable like you have done and use the attribute .IsEnabled . 

 I've now also added a logic app component to re-enable the schedule but trying to tune that a bit better now too if you're open to messaging, I can show you the other part I'm tying to do

Comment: Thanks! May I know what is the other part you are trying?